# You have already activated rack 1.5.2, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.4.5. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn, digital-ocean

Hello i have been trying to install our site to digital ocean with unicorn, and past 3 days i have been trying to solve this issue.
i'm able to run success full bundle install, i had error of db credential i have solved it that and few syntax error it was showing in putty.but whenever i try to access site via browser it shows |504 Gateway Time-out" error.

```
$GEM_PATH : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global
$GEM_HOME : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/
```

i'm using RVM. and selected 2.1.3.

```
bundle exec rails s
```

Shows succesufull starting of app and WEBrick start of server.[image]

I look around on stack overflow, i don't think i have to uninstall other rack version to solve this as i'm using RVM. Please let me know your suggestions .

Edits!!!!!
gemfile

```
gem 'rack', '1.4.5'
```

gemfile.lock

```
rack (1.4.5)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: The server was hosting a stock rails 4 app i removed that and deployed my rails 3.2 app ,if this helps.

Comment: can you change the gem 'rake' version to 1.5.2?

Comment: Your screen shot doesn't help at all. Instead, copy the text and paste it in place of the screen shot, and make sure you've formatted it so its readable. That allows the search engines also search the text.

Comment: I deleted 1.5.2 and use 1.4.5 now it.s working. it was not able to use 1.5.2 because dependency issues. But that's guys.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting unnecessary rack version and using 1.4.5 solved my issues. Thanks.